# a relative few vs. a relatively few

Tags: pronouns

> Engineers in World War I dug through the earth to build serpentine trenches borne from horrifically clear logic.
>
> If enemy soldiers ever breached it, the zigzagging pattern would prevent them from shooting in a straight line down the length of the trench — leaving only **a relative few** exposed to gunfire or shrapnel.

Is **a relatively few** possible here?
Is there any difference in meaning?
If both are possible, which is better and why? Both semantic and syntactic analyses are appreciated.

Comment: *Few* can stand alone as a pronoun in the example sentence. But for *a relatively few* to work, you would need a noun after *few* (e.g. *leaving only a relatively few people exposed*). That's perhaps because there's no antecedent for the "swallowed up" noun that would allow a "fused-head" or elliptical noun interpretation (*enemy soldiers* is not that noun) . . .

Comment: @TinfoilHat Please see this Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+relative+few+are%2Ca+relatively+few+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20relative%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20relatively%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20relative%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20relatively%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Please see: [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=85199007)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Which does include examples like _a relatively few think that costs will come down_; _to favor a relatively few at the top in a democracy_; _a relatively few have the chance to_; _in the hope of saving a relatively few_. So how could you say that "for a relatively few to work, you would need a noun after few"?

Comment: Do those 4 out of 85 examples show *few* having an antecedent?

Comment: @TinfoilHat You don't need an antecedent in order for "a few" to function as an NP. Why should you need one in order for "a relatively few" to function as an NP?

Comment: Consider *few are chosen* vs *a few are chosen*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Please stop beating around the bush and start making your point directly.

Comment: I don't have a point yet. Just clues. What does *few* refer to in your example sentence?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I think it refers to soldiers deployed in the trench to fight the incoming enemy soldiers.

Comment: Perhaps. But they are nowhere to be seen as antecedents.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I don't know why you're obsessed with antecedents. Pronouns in general sometimes do have overt antecedents but they sometimes don't. You can call it covert antecedents or simply context.

Comment: From Canada: "a relatively few", in any context, sounds wrong to me.  In order to say "relatively few", you have to lose the indefinite article for it to sound okay to me.

Comment: May we ignore any suggestion of building "serpentine trenches" and the more so, "borne from horrifically clear logic"?

Unusually, here it matters not whether you use  relatively few possible here? Is there any difference in meaning? If both are possible, which is better and why? Both semantic and syntactic analyses are appreciated.

Comment: Here, it matters not whether you use "a relative few" or "relatively few", so long as you avoid both "relative few" without the article or "a relatively few" with it…

May we ignore any suggestion of building "serpentine trenches" and the more so, "borne from horrifically clear logic"? If you insist they matter, can you tell us how?

Comment: @Spitemaster How does _A comparatively few are..._ sound to your ear vis-à-vis _A comparative few are..._? How about _A very few are..._? Note both _comparatively_ and _very_ are adverbs, just like _relatively_.

Comment: Neither of those sound okay to me.  *A comparative few are...* sounds okay, if a little awkward - it's not something that I might say in normal speech.  *Very few are...* or *Comparatively few are...* are what I'd go for.

Comment: "Relatively few" is plural.  "Relative few" is singular.

Answer (score 2):

Though 'relatively few' is far more modern-sounding than 'a relative few', in this case it doesn't work as there really needs to be a defining nominal in ' ... leaving ____ exposed to ...', or at least a clear antecedent.

' ... leaving only relatively few of the defending soldiers exposed to ...' works and is more modern-sounding (but lengthier and less punchy). Here, 'a relative few' works well, giving something of a WWI period flavour.

Churchill knew that the 'antecedents', the referents, would be globally understood in 'Never in the field of human conflict was so much owed by so many to so few,' when he was of course referring to the heroic efforts of the Royal Air Force crews  fighting (and winning) the Battle of Britain.

Using 'a relatively few' in place of 'a relative few' certainly is not unknown (eg 'A relatively few were banded at older ages' [[Coloniality in the Cliff Swallow: The Effect of Group Size ... Brown & Brown 1996](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RYwlytLag_IC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%22a+relatively+few+were%22&source=bl&ots=7q6wtxw8Le&sig=ACfU3U26TD3IDmI8xCV48ge-9ZzAQyT4ag&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20relatively%20few%20were%22&f=false)], but without a headnoun like 'soldiers' it sounds very clumsy to my ears. I'd class it as not ungrammatical, but better avoided (especially in non-period writing). The expression probably jars because of the juxtaposition of adverb (-or-is-it-now?) and [pro-]nominalised quantifier; it probably exists as a reduced form, deleting words without concern for the grammatical mess being left.

Comment: If you're saying 'of the defending soldiers' is necessary after 'a relatively few' but not after 'a relative few', please tell me why. I  for one think the PP can be ellipted after either.

Comment: Sorry; adding to answer to address this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To my mind this simply bears out what my Latin teacher told us sixty years ago. Good English is to a large extent not about grammar, but about idiom and usage. However is not the key point here that "relatively" is an adverb, qualifying "leaving", whereas "relative" is an adjective qualifying the noun "few". And further complicating matters is that "few" is one of those nouns that works both with an article and without. Though where an adjective is present it seems to require an article.

Comment: ... No; as clearly stated above, 'a relatively few were banded' is not considered unacceptable (though I'd never use it).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here's an Ngram comparing 'a relative few are' and 'a relatively few' are. They are comparable although the former is more popular after around the 1980s: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+relative+few+are%2Ca+relatively+few+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20relative%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20relatively%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20relative%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20relatively%20few%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @EdwinAshworth More importantly, this Ngram of 'a * few are' reveals that the most popular term of this construction is "a very few are" where I'm sure 'very' is an adverb: http://tiny.cc/b05vkz

Comment: One advantage of "a relative few" is that it describes an actual group of men, whereas "relatively few" is a quantifier and therefore a bit more abstract and in turn, less effective.  Also, "a relative few" acts as a callback to the famous St Crispins day speech from Shakespeare's Henry V - *"We few, we happy few, we band of brothers..."*

Comment: ... I _knew_ there was a famous one before the Churchill masterpiece.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I don't know what you're talking about. In 'a relatively few are...', 'relatively few' is not a quantifier. If there's any quantifier there, it's 'a relatively few' with 'people' ellipted.

Comment: @listeneva I was referring to the usage of "relatively few" as in *"leaving only relatively few of the defending soldiers exposed to ."*, as suggested in the parent answer to this comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to observe the distinction between *few*, which is a negative trigger meaning 'not many'

- *Few have ever seen him angry.*

and *a few*, which is affirmative, not negative, and doesn't trigger NPIs like *ever*

- *A few people finally showed up.*
- **A few people have ever seen him angry.*

They are not the same construction. And they don't have the same syntax, either.

*Few* is a quantifier, and it modifies a noun phrase. Consequently it can be modified by an adverb like *relatively*

- *Relatively few people have ever seen him angry.*

*A few*, on the other hand, is a determiner, normally used as a noun phrase standing for whatever is being quantified, and as such it is modified by an adjective like *relative*

- *Engineers had to build a relative few trenches.* (by comparison)
- *Engineers had to build relatively few trenches.* (intrinsically negative)

But not the other way around.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. You say, _a few_ is modified by an adjective like _relative_ because it (_a few_) is a determiner. But in _a relative few trenches_, _relative_ does not modify _a few_ but _few_. // Moreover, _a relatively few_ used to be and still is much more productive than _a relative few_: https://bit.ly/38JYedR

Comment: Why did you even mention the negative 'few' when my question is specifically about only the positive 'a (relative/relatively) few'?

Comment: @JK2: What the ngram doesn't show is that *a relatively few* is almost always followed by a noun.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Can you prove that? At least this Ngram doesn't support your claim: https://bit.ly/2TM8AW9

Comment: @JK2: Scroll up to my COCA link in the comments under the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

**A relative few**

> **Few - OED**
> **B. […] noun**.
>
> **II. Noun uses**.
>
> **2. With indefinite article**.
>
> ** (a) A small number of people or things. Also with modifying adjective, as a faithful few, a select few, etc. **
>
> 1993   Albuquerque (New Mexico) Jrnl. 25 Jan. (Business Outlook section) 27 (advt.) *MBA Programs are not all created equal. A select few are granted national accreditation*.

Thus, 1. “*[…] leaving only a relative few exposed to gunfire or shrapnel* Few is a noun -> A few of those present; a good few

**Relatively few**

> **Few OED**
>
> **A. adj. and determiner**.
>
> **1. Not many; amounting only to a small number. Also preceded by modifying words, esp. *but, so, too, very*. Without a preceding determiner, as here, few usually implies antithesis with ‘many’**.
>
> **(a) Modifying a plural noun either specified or implied by the context.**
>
> 1845   G. Budd On Diseases of the Liver 280   *Among the numbers of bodies that I examined..very few, indeed hardly any, had gall-stones*. [Edit: Here the implied noun is “bodies”]

Thus, 2. “*[…] leaving only relatively few exposed to gunfire or shrapnel*”. – few is an adjective modifying an implied noun - in your case the implied noun will be “defenders” (or something similar.)

Comment: The 'few' in both (1) and (2) functions as head of an NP, but you say the one in (1) is a noun and that the one in (2) is an adjective modifying an implied noun. What gives?

Comment: Adjectives functioning as nouns gives...

Comment: @listeneva's example includes an indefinite article sandwiched by two adverbs: *only a relatively few*. At best that is borderline ungrammatical. What say you?

Comment: Only is an adverb and can be added freely. Consider the OED example above: "*A select few are granted national accreditation*", which we can front with "only."

Comment: *Select* is an adjective. Does, for example *only a comparably few* pass any sniff test?

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: @TinfoilHat According to this Ngram of 'only a * few are', by far the most productive word for * is the adverb 'very': https://bit.ly/2W9dXAg

Comment: @JK2: It's hard to see usage of a phrase after a few results of the ngrams, but if you look at the first of those for *a relatively few*, you can see that when a noun does not follow, there is a clear and present antecedent for it.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The ngram I have shown you below John Lawler's answer is for the construction where _few_ is not followed by a noun. You can't seem to see that ngram and can only focus on "a few results of the ngram". That's like you can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: @JK2: Look at the texts using this without a noun. There is a real antecedent. Not an imaginary, elliptical one. One that is there in the same sentence or immediately preceding it.

Comment: @TinfoilHat And you're saying the OP's 'few' doesn't have a "real antecedent"?

Comment: @JK2: I am going somewhere with this; I just don't know quite where yet. And then to figure out which grammar's term to couch an analysis in . . . I do know, natively, that *a relatively few* has very limited applications, and the OP's example does not qualify.

Comment: @JK2: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying: the OP's *few* does not have real antecedent. If that isn't obvious from the sentences provided, it is by viewing the source quote. And *few* the noun doesn't need one, but *a relatively few* does.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Maybe 'a relatively few' resists being a fused-head NP, whereas 'a relative few' (or 'relatively few' without 'a') doesn't. That said, it's not going to be straightforward to articulate why.

Answer (score 0):

No, *a relatively few* is not really possible as used in your example—not in normal usage anyway:

> **If enemy soldiers ever breached it, the zigzagging pattern would prevent them from shooting in a straight line down the length of the
>   trench — leaving only **a relatively few** exposed to gunfire or
>   shrapnel.* (incorrect)

You would need a noun following *a relatively few* for that to work:

> *If enemy soldiers ever breached it, the zigzagging pattern would prevent them from shooting in a straight line down the length of the
>   trench — leaving only **a relatively few defenders** exposed to gunfire
>   or shrapnel.*

Or you would need a clear and present noun antecedent in the preceding text in order to yield the "determiner-head (noun) fusion" interpretation that would allow *few* to be modified by the adverb *relatively*. That is, you have to have something to fuse:

> *If enemy soldiers ever breached the trench, its zigzagging pattern would protect most of **the defenders** from a straight line of fire —
>   leaving only **a relatively few** exposed to gunfire or shrapnel.*

No fusion makes *a few* a noun phrase, as here:

> **few**, *adj.*, *pron.*, and *n.*
>   **II.** Noun uses. **2.** With indefinite article. **a.** A small number of people or things. Also with modifying adjective, as **a
>   faithful few**, **a select few**, etc
>
> <sub>1775   S. JOHNSON *Taxation No Tyranny* 60:   The whole town of
>   Boston is distressed for the misdemeanour of a few.
>   1947 
>   *Clearing House* 21 429/1:   My class was unusually apathetic. Nevertheless, there were a few who were alert.
>  2003   J. R. LENNON
>   MAILMAN i. iv. 209:   A few have ‘dressed down’ and wear shorts and
>   golf shirts; others are in suit and tie.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/) (login
>   required)</sub>

As a noun phrase, *a few* takes an adjective (e.g. *relative*)—not an adverb (e.g. *relatively*)—modifier.

Back to the noun antecedent issue. [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=85487901) shows how *a relatively few* is used:

Of the eighty-five results, all but six have a noun phrase following *a relatively few*. Of those six, two contain accompanying antecedents:

> *The poll also clearly shows **a lot of people** think Obamacare will make health insurance more expensive and **a relatively few** think
>   that costs will come down.*
>
> *. . . alcoholism and drug abuse, for example, which kill **380,000 Americans** every year. The saving of byes is worth spending money on,
>   but it doesn't make much sense to spend vast amounts in the hope of
>   saving **a relatively few** when we can not seem to afford to spend
>   anything like those amounts on things that cause hundreds of times
>   more deaths.*

One is a bit backwards:

> *Put simply, it has been a boon for **a relatively few**, including **some firms** that had strongly supported the passage of the ordinance and were already well-positioned to receive its benefits. For others,
>   newly formed, it has meant little. # During a three-year period at the
>   height of construction activity for the $ 4.2 billion Denver
>   International Airport, **a relatively few firms** got most of the
>   minority business.*

And three have no clear antecedents (of which two are transcriptions of Bill Moyers speaking in interviews);

> *But this same culture becomes radically inegalitarian if only *a relatively few* have the chance to prosper financially.*
>
> *We have reached a dangerous level of extremism -- that is destroying our world environment, and creating a social structure that benefits
>   **a relatively few** at the expense of the majority.*
>
> *How can this happen? How could Washington turn its back on the broad middle class to favor **a relatively few** at the top in a democracy?*

In any case, except for an extemporaneous Bill and a couple of others, we really don't do that. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: You say this: As a noun phrase, a few takes an adjective (e.g. _relative_)—not an adverb (e.g. _relatively_)—modifier. But don't you agree that the adverb _very_ can replace _relative_ in the OP?

Comment: No, not really. We still have the same problem: a very few *what*? a relatively few *what*? You need a head noun (syntactically present, not inferred) to fuse with *few*. Otherwise, *a few* **is** the noun.

Comment: You pretend that "a relatively few" or "a very few" without any following head noun makes it difficult for you to understand what "few" means unless there's an explicit noun antecedent. But I think you actually don't have any problem understanding what "few" means in these constructions as well as in "a relative few". Why would you pretend that you don't understand something when you actually do?

Comment: You don't need a noun following *a few*. But you do need one preceding *a few* somewhere if you want to modify *a few* with an adverb. You will likely be understood whatever you choose to do, but that is a separate matter.

Comment: If you don't have any problem understanding what 'few' means in the OP with 'relatively' substituting for 'relative', the objection to 'relatively' has nothing to do with the absence of a clear, explicit antecedent of 'few', be the objection itself valid or not.

Comment: I *understand* your OP example sentences **despite** the grammar. What does *it* refer to in *If enemy soldiers ever breached it*? The writer seems to be a bit undisciplined.

Comment: I think _it_ refers to _the trench_ in the main clause.

Comment: There is no *the trench* in the main clause—only *serpentine trenches*.

Comment: I'm talking about the main clause of the same sentence the if-clause is in. And you're talking about the prior sentence.

Comment: Grammatically, *it* points to *pattern*, which makes no sense and leaves the reader to sort things out. *A relative few* is odd with no antecedent, but at least it's structurally sufficicient. *A relatively few* doesn't work there. If understandability is your benchmark for correctness, then there's nothing to worry about. Otherwise turn to the rules (e.g. the dictionary) or the usage (e.g. the corpus). Those two don't always agree, but they do in this case.